# Need help with an edit

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54119/in-h%C3%BCckels-rule-can-n-be-any-integer/54169#54169) I proposed an edit, then found I had made a typo (wanted *sustituted*, got *dybstituted*).  Can't correct because I am stuck in peer review, and if I have to re-edit I am back in peer review.  What can I do?

Comment: I just reviewed your edit and rejected it because I don't think that's what the OP was trying to say.

Comment: Then what can be done?  Olah's eork was misreported, and now my attempt to correct the record is rejected.  Will this never be resolved?

Comment: What I meant was that the OP meant to write dianion, not disubstituted. The edit was not needed in the first place.

Comment: @bon No, the edit was okay in itself except for the typo that was introduced (which Jannis Andreska then corrected with approve & edit) and the grammar mistake that was introduced (which I took to correcting myself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was nothing you could do. Once an edit is pending review, it is stuck there. (And if a reviewer misclicks — I’ve had that; I wanted to click *Reject & edit* and hit *Reject* instead — they’re stuck there, too.)

If you check out the [help centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/editing), there is nothing explicit on the subject. However, there is the sentence:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

If you want to, you can read this as ‘pay attention to what you edit, so that you don’t introduce any errors in the process.’

---

Then again, that is what the *Accept & edit*  function in the review queue is for. Reviewers should be looking out for what the edit suggestor changed and whether it introduced errors. Unfortunately, this process could have been improved in the case of this edit of your’s.

Comment: Thanks for eventually solving it.  One day I'll hit 2000 rep and have a lot fewer headaches.  :-S